# Цикл обхода файлов и удаление ненужного кода

Tags: скрипт, файлы, php, циклы

Здравствуйте.

Недавно обнаружил на своем сайте, что во все фалы с расширением PHP был вписан сторонний код, везде одинаковый что-то типа этого

```
eval(base64_decode("DQpl....и тд"));
```

Как бы мне смастерить php скрипт, который бы пробежался по всем файлам сайта и вычистил эту дрянь оттуда!

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: лучше найдите дыру и не забывайте о бекапах данных

Answer (score 4):

Простейший способ:

Мысль такая:

```
function elav(){ // Тут нет ошибки. Это не переопределение. Это другая функция с похожим названием
return '';
}
function bsae64_decode(){
return '';
}

function dirReplace($path){
$files = scandir($path);
foreach($files as $file){
if($file!='.' && $file!='..' && !is_dir($path.'/'.$file)){
  $str = file_get_contents($path.'/'.$file);
  str_replace('eval(base64_decode','elav(bsae64_decode',$str);
  file_put_contents($path.'/'.$file,$str);
}else{
  dirReplace($path.'/'.$file);
}
}
}
```

Более сложный -

```
preg_replace('/eval\s*\(base64_decode\s*\(\s*\'[^\'"()]+\'\s*)\s*)/','//HERE WAS ALIEN. Ha-ha!',$str);
```

Comment: советую удалить из ответа вариант с переопределением стандартных функций...  
это равносильно научиьт человека такому:  
define true false;  

+1 к регуляркам.

Comment: посмотрите внимательно на названия.

Comment: А команда find (с вызовом какго-нибудь sed/awk/perl) не спасёт отца русской демократии?

Comment: Отца спасет. А файлы - вряд ли.

Comment: @knes что-нибудь типа

    find /php-dir -name '*.php' -exec grep -v 'eval(base64_decode("DQpl' {} >$$ \; -exec mv $$ {} \;

Comment: это если есть доступ к консоли. :)

Answer (score 0):

Написал себе такой вариант:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.php" -o -name "*.phtml" \) -exec sed -i 's/eval(base64_decode(".*"));//g' {} \;
```

Comment: И что, работает? А не должно бы...

Блин, код форматировать надо, а то звёздочки были не видны.